# Smooth Scroll HTML and jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, scroll

Good evening, I haven't been able to solve this problem for a few days. When I click href to go to the section of the page in question, the scroll goes slightly further making a nasty final snap. This is my code, can you tell me why?

```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
       $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {

        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
       if (this.hash !== "") {

         // Prevent default anchor click behavior
         event.preventDefault();

         // Store hash
         var hash = this.hash;

         // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
         // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
         $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top-90
         }, 900, function(){

           // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
           window.location.hash = hash;
           });
         } // End if
       });
     })
  </script>
```

Comment: The nasty final snap you’re seeing is because your first telling the browser to animate to a position 90px above the scrollTop value you’re going to, *but* then, when you update the `window.location.hash` to the new value, you’re telling the browser to go to a new location, which is 90px from where it is now. You can eliminate the snap by adding 5.625rem padding to your anchor tags so that the content starts below the tag. The tag can be at the top of the screen (below your navbar?), but the content will be 90px from the top of the screen.

Comment: if you remove 90 the scroll goes too low. It can be solved by adding the padding-top as you said but it is going to alter and white spaces. Are there no other solutions? Because the code I got it from w3school and it works perfectly so I wanted to understand why my no.